# CSS selector priority between id and tag

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I know that `id` is more specific than `class` and `class` is more specific than `tag`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sample document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="first">
      <strong class="carrot">C</strong>ascading
      <strong class="spinach">S</strong>tyle
      <strong class="spinach">S</strong>heets
    </p>
    <p id="second">
          <strong>C</strong>ascading
          <strong>S</strong>tyle
          <strong>S</strong>heets
        </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

style1.css

```
strong { color: red; }
.carrot { color: orange; }
.spinach { color: green; }
#first { font-style: italic; }
#second { color: cyan; }
```

The result:

[image: output]

It is just like I expected in the first paragraph. But I expected the first letters of the second paragraph would also be cyan since `id` is more specific than `tag`.

Comment: first you need to know, how the browser will react for id, class and tags. So that you can easily control.. btw do you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/8gFHF/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS specificity does not force descendants of selected elements to inherit property values from their parent.

`#second` does not match the element `<strong>`, but `strong` does.

Answer (score 0):

As I am of the opinion that Quentin's answer is not quite correct, or at least a bit misleading, here is my explanation:

Your ID selector matches the element with the respective ID.

Regarding the inheritance have a look at the [CSS Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specified-value).
Paragraph 6.1.1 Specified values says:

> User agents must first assign a specified value to each property based on the following mechanisms (in order of precedence):
>
> 1. If the cascade results in a value, use it.
> 2. Otherwise, if the property is inherited and the element is not the root of the document tree, use the computed value of the parent element.
> 3. Otherwise use the property's initial value. The initial value of each property is indicated in the property's definition.

So the color value of the parent element (`<p>`) would be inherited (not all properties are inheritable) to the child element (`<strong>`), but due to your style rule for the strong element, therefore point 1 meets.

Or in other words: Inheritance only takes effect, when there is no other style rule defined for the appropriate element.

Also be aware of that all user agents have a default stylesheet!

Comment: What do you see as incorrect or misleading in @Quentin’s answer? I understand what your answer says, but I find it somewhat confusing—for example, browser default style sheets have nothing to do with the issue, and the correct technical term is “inheritance”, not “heredity”.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - corrected. There is nothing "wrong" with Quentin's answer, but "CSS specificity does not force descendants of selected elements to inherit property values from their parent." is the same as one would say:"The weather does not force descendants of selected elements to inherit property values from their parent."! It is also correct, but did not hit the point why the result is other than the OP expected. The issue is in the second sentence:"#second does not match the element <strong>, but strong does.", but not easily to recognize.

Comment: And the reason why I also pointed out the "user agents default style sheets" is, that they also may affect the inheritance for the same reason (point 1) - see [6.4 The cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade)